# Получить расширение загружаемого файла php

Tags: php, fileupload

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу получить расширение загружаемого файла.

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/home/aasinua/crm.contrust.club/uploads/';
$ext = pathinfo($uploaddir, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . 'название' . $ext))
{
    print "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
} else {
    print "There some errors!";
}
?>
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

> *В чем проблема?*

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь получить расширение не у файла, а у директории `/home/aasinua/crm.contrust.club/uploads/`

```
$uploaddir = '/home/aasinua/crm.contrust.club/uploads/';
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . 'название.' . $ext)) {
    print "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
} else {
    print "There some errors!";
}
```

---

Инфо: [Загрузка файлов методом POST](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```